# Forward options from a Plug.Router to another Plug.Router

Tags: elixir, plug

### Background

I have a `Plug.Router` application that receives some options. I need to pass these options to other plugs via `forward` but I don't know how to do it.

### Code

This is the main router. It receives requests and decides where to forward them.

```
defmodule MyApp.Web.Router do
  use Plug.Router

  plug(:match)
  plug(:dispatch)

  #Here I check that I get options! 
  def init(father_opts), do: IO.puts("#{__MODULE__} => #{inspect father_opts}")

  forward "/api/v1", to: MyApp.Web.Route.API.V1, init_opts: father_opts??
end
```

As you can probably guess, this won't work. I want my `forward` call to access the `father_opts` this router is receiving, but I can't access them.

At first I though about the following code snippet:

```
def init(opts), do: opts

def call(conn, father_opts) do
  forward "/api/v1", to: MyApp.Web.Route.API.V1, init_opts: father_opts
end
```

But this doesn't work because I can't put a `forward` inside a `call`.

So how do I achieve my objective using `forward`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an option adding a top-level plug that will store the father options on `private` and you can fetch that on children `call`.

Something like:

```
defmodule Example.Router do
  def init(opts), do: opts
  def call(conn, options) do
    Example.RouterMatch.call(Plug.Conn.put_private(conn, :father_options, options), Example.RouterMatch.init(options))
  end
end

defmodule Example.RouterMatch do
  use Plug.Router

  plug :match
  plug :dispatch

  forward "/check", to: Example.Route.Check
  forward "/dispatch", to: Example.Plug.Dispatch
end
```

Then you can fetch options on the conn in `Example.Route.Check.call/2`.

Comment: The issue with this approach is that it is not forwarding anything. I want to pass options when I forward the request. Having a top level router won't help with that.

Comment: Yes, it is not forwarding but making it available on the children. After reading the plug code I don't think that it is possible and because that I added this suggestion.